# GIT : Can't push data from local to server

Tags: git

I'm new with Git, may be this question is duplicated but I can't even find an right answer for myself.
I have an dedicated server (for exam : xxx.199.209.177)
I have project on my local machine, so now I want to commit and push my change to my remote server.

These are some step I set up with it.
1) In remote server

```
cd /var/www/html/
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ mkdir .git
$ cd .git
$ git --bare init
```

And on my local machine

```
$ cd /srv/www/html/
$ git clone root@xxx.199.209.177:/var/www/html/test/.git
     warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
$ cd test
// make some change here
$ git status
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "test"
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 217 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To root@xxx.199.209.177:/var/www/html/test/.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master]
```

But when I come back to remote host

```
$ cd test
$ ls -l
total 0
```

there's nothing here

I think I missing some important steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a non-bare repository your repository is stored in `.git` and you working tree outside of it.

With a bare repository there is only one directory storing the actual repository and there is *no* working tree connected to it. Therefore you cannot directly see the files in a bare repository.

It usually works as follows:

```
server$ git init --bare /remote/path/test.git
client$ cd /local/path
client$ git clone user@server:/remote/path/test.git
client$ ls -la test
```

In this case you have one repository on the server at `/remote/path/test.git` and another repository on the client at `/local/path/test/.git` and one working tree on the client at the `/local/path/test`. There won't be a working tree for the bare repository on the server.

---

It looks like you are trying to sync a www-server using git. This will not work this way.
Bare repositories don't have a working tree showing the files and for a non-bare repository git will not change the working tree after a push. (In fact it will refuse the push if that branch is checked out.)

You probably want three different repositories:

- a local repository, where you change your files.
- a central bare repository where you push your files to
- another non-bare repository for you www-server used for pulling from the central server.

If you really want the server repository to update automatically you need a hook on the central repository which (after each received push) changes to the www repository and pulls the changes.

Answer (score 0):

1) You do not need these steps

```
mkdir .git
$ cd .git
```

`git --bare init` command will sets up the necessary .git folder and files

2) Run `ls -la` instead of `ls -l`, because -a option do not hide entries starting with .

Answer (score 0):

The remote used is initialized as a bare repository. This means that it will store everything git specific in a `.git` folder but it will not have a working directory.

This is common for remote repos since they should generally be used for only push/pull/clone operations.

Hope you understood the point. You can verify your changes by running a `git log` on the remote server which should show all you latest commits.